# What are some good podcasts for game developers to listen to?

Tags: education

This could include specific game dev, general dev or general game podcasts.

Please provide a brief description along with links.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[Another Castle](http://gamedesignadvance.com/?page_id=1616) - Professionals talk game design.

[Game Developers Radio](http://www.gamedevradio.com/) - Great guests, a different game or development platform discussed each week.

[Brainy Gamer](http://www.brainygamer.com/the_brainy_gamer/podcast/) - Game design from designer, journalist, academic and player perspectives.

[DigiPen](https://www.digipen.edu/news-and-events/podclass-the-digipen-podcast/) - Professionals and educators talk games.

[IndieGamePod](http://www.indiegamepod.com/) Interviews with developers about their games.

[A life well wasted](http://alifewellwasted.com/) Arty, philosophical trip around gaming culture.

[Game Audio Podcast](http://www.gameaudiopodcast.com/): Self-explanatory. Found it while searching for a talk on footsteps in games.

[The Debug Log](http://thedebuglog.com/) Professionals talks game dev; Relevant guests is invited, and relevant approaches and software is discussed.

[Doom Ninja Podcast](http://www.doombrowski.com/podcast): Indie studio Doombrowski talks games and development. Also includes video game live streaming perspective from co-host.

Answer (score 13):

There is [Industry Broadcast](http://www.industrybroadcast.com/) which describes itself as "Bringing the Collective Insight of the Gaming Industry to your ears".

Basically it features audio versions of existing online articles ... if you prefer to listen rather than read or you have time to kill on your commute then they may be of some use!

Comment: This is another great one. I find it much easier to find time to listen than to read. So far the content seems insightful and interesting.

Answer (score 8):

[Irrational Behavior](https://irrationalgames.ghoststorygames.com/tag/irrational-podcasts/) - Developers at Irrational Games discussing various aspects of development.

Comment: +1 for production value of podcast.  Nothing very in-depth, but entertaining and well executed.

Answer (score 7):

[Infinite Ammo Podcast](http://infiniteammo.ca/blog/tag/podcast/): Interviews with indie game developers.

[Looking Glass Podcast](http://gambit.mit.edu/updates/audio/looking_glass_studios_podcast/): Interviews with developers who once formed that great team.

Comment: I just discovered the Infinite Ammo Podcast recently, and it quickly became one of my favorites. It doesn't get too technical, but there's a lot of really meaty, honest conversations about the design process and the challenges facing smaller indie teams. Really great insight into the indie game dev community.

Answer (score 5):

[Another Castle](http://gamedesignadvance.com/?page_id=1616) is a game design podcast that focuses on the game development scene in the New York area. Sometime the audio isn't that good (they record a lot in restaurants) but the interviewees are always interesting.

Comment: You're right about the audio, but it seems to be worth listening to anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I've listened to some of the [GameDevRadio](http://www.gamedevradio.com/) ones, there are not a lot and they come rarely but they are often fun to check out.

They talk about varied topics, the ones there now are Flash (2 part), SDL, Unity, Push Button Engine for example.

The shows are roughly an hour, often more.

Comment: I'm in the middle of my second episode. So far it's a great example of what I was looking for. Episodes seem to have a fair amount of depth.

Answer (score 3):

[Flammable Penguins](http://www.claire-blackshaw.com/blog/category/podcast/) - New casual podcast with me and my co-workers from Mere-Mortals. Feedback always appreciated.

The dev casts I listen to have all been listed already.

Answer (score 2):

The [Kingdom of Loathing](http://www.kingdomofloathing.com/) guys run [an entertaining podcast](http://radio.kingdomofloathing.com/) (or two - [Video Games Hotdog](http://videogameshotdog.com/)) that often talks about game design, balance and interacting with their community. Video Games Hotdog talk about video games in general.

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys I am the creator of "[The Game Developer's Radio](https://soundcloud.com/the-game-developers-radio/)" want to say thanks for linking to my show! It's been on a bit of a Hiatus for a while, but I finally released a new episode :-D And will be releasing plenty more, very soon!

Also if you want a list of more game dev podcast links id recommend checking out this blog post http://blog.iainlobb.com/2010/07/gamedev-and-indie-games-podcasts.html has tons of links to game dev podcasts.

Answer (score 1):

I find the Giant Bombcast pretty entertaining, even if it's not so much game-development as it is just gaming

Answer (score 0):

Great lists here.. Glad to see [www.industrybroadcast.com](http://www.industrybroadcast.com) plugged.  Back recording articles again after a nice almost year long hiatus.  The podcast is certainly a bit more dry and serious as the topics covered can get insanely indepth, theoretical and technical.

Outside of my biased opinion though I have to say A Life Well Wasted tops my list, not just in this genre but of any podcast I have ever listened to.. It is absolutely and purely brilliant

Answer (score 0):

[IndieGames.com Podcast](http://indiegames.com/podcast/) has a lot of good interviews with indie developers. The interviews tend to be framed from a journalist/player perspective, but there's still a lot of decent design talk.